# My Django Admin fields does not show non asccii data correctly

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

I have a Django 1.11 Project with Mysql 5.7. When I write non-ASCII characters in the Django admin fields e.g. (`چترال کا  منظر`), they display as `????????????`.

It does seem my database is not storing the data as I want it to; here is the my database charset.
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Interesting. Are you using python 2?

Comment: Yes I am on python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by running the following command on my table.

```
alter table `tagging_taggeditem` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

After that I had to resave the django model to populate the values correctly.